# Combine Laravel with vue and react by vite , how manage multiple app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, architecture, vite

Trying to combination all in one super application that Handel multiple app over Laravel server side and react and Vue client side.. how can I 5 app in one frame work..
An One app for reservations hotel room, second for shopping , third for reserve flying ticket, other for reserve pool, an the fifth for register in driving test and so...
Is there any good architecture for multiple app run run server side to Handel all together?

Trying Multiple app architecture in server side and expected in complex methods

Comment: Have you tried using inertia js ?

Comment: If server side is only rest api with no server side rendering, this doesn't limit you to any architecture at all. The question isn't specific enough, also isn't suited for SO, try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: No I didn't use inertia.